# The optimal storing of user's array in a database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database

Friends, i need your help. 
I am working with php+mysql. But i've run into a little problem. I need to store a special array in DB, every user has own array of his own data, that belongs only to him. An array is changed every time, when the user uses the application. So, the arrays must be changed very often.

To put it simply, i am creating an education application. We have a table of **items** for learning *(id, item_name)* and a table of **users** *(id, user_name)*.
Whenever, a user learns new item from item's table, we have to add the item in the user's array, that stores all his items, which he learnt.

My question is: How to implement the optimal storing of the array in database?

I have only two possible variants in my head:

1) To create new individual table  **user_item_relationship** *(id, user_id, item_id)*

The problem of the  variant is: I am planning the app to be high-load. And every time i have to fetch from database all items that a specific user learnt. Every user will have approximately 500 items. But if the application has at least 10000 users, the table will be enormous (5 000 000 rows, maybe bigger). So, the variant is gonna be very bad, when the app has many users.

2) The second variant, which i am currently using is:

to not create other tables, but simply store the array of learnt items of any user in JSON in a **user's table** , so the table would look like *(id, user_name, learnt_items)*.

In the variant,  the perfomance of the app doesn't depend on quantity of users. It only depends on, how many items a user learnt. But the minus of the approach is: every time, when user learns new item, i have to fetch huge JSON-string from DB, decode it, add new item to the array, encode again and update the field in DB by sending the hulk of text back. The problem is: if a user learnt many items, it becomes slower and slower...

---

Maybe there is something better? Maybe there is ability to push only one item to user's array in DB? I just have been working only with mysql. But i am ready to change my stack, if it helps to solve the problem.

Comment: That sounds a lot like "NoSQL".

Comment: I paid my attention to MongoDb, do you think  the DB will solve the problem? I know that  NoSQL  stores data like in json-objects. Is there a way to push element in such array without fetching the array entirely to backend, adding the element, and sending back to DB?

Comment: if you create index on `user_id` in `user_item_relationship`, the retrieval should be pretty fast even in case of large number of entries in the table..

Comment: Even there will be 5 billions rows? And the point is: every new relation **user_item** is put in the end of the `user_item_relationship` table. So relations of different users become mixed in the table. And if the table contains huge quantity of rows, the perfomance will be awful. At least the table needs to be sorted. And it creates new question about the sorting...                     So, maybe NoSQL is good for the task? I am just not familiar with NoSQL yet.